# Using the Java.io.* to read files

Tags: java, class

I have to write a method within a class to read files. Do I need to import the java.io.* in the class, or does that have to be done in the main that calls on the method?

Comment: You have to add the import for all the classes you wish to use within the current class

Comment: Have you tried importing inside main?  What did the compiler say?

Answer (score 3):

The `import` declarations belong at the top of the translation unit where the reference is made. Strictly speaking, you do not have to import anything: importing is a convenience that lets you avoid typing up the full name of the class being used (i.e. `BufferedReader` instead of `java.io.BufferedReader`).

The caller does not have to import anything related to the *implementation* of methods in the classes that it's using. That's one of the virtues of encapsulation: the caller needs to know what it calls, but it is firmly insulated from the implementation details of the classes that it uses.

Comment: brilliant answer, I'd have never thought about doing that

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
import java.io.*;
class MyClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        FileReader f = new FileReader ("myfile.txt");
    }
}
```